# what is the way to iterate the $resource.get other than doing $promise.then

Tags: angularjs

Once I receive the document say `$scope.var = $resource.get(/*one record*/)`.. I would need to read the received nested object structure (which is now in $scope.var) in order to display each and every field.

I am not able to access the key-value pairs that are present in the `$scope.var`. So I found a way in doing this using `$scope.var.$promise.then(callback)` but the format of the $scope.var is changed.

for example:

```
before parsing:
When I console to see what is in $scope.var, it shows as - 
Resource: {$Promise: Promise, $resolved: false}
/*key-value pairs of the object*/

after parsing using $promise.then:
Here the console says
Object {_id: "...", ...}
/*key-value pairs of the object*/
```

Because of the above format difference I am facing the problem when trying to $update using $resource. Which says `$update is not a function`.

Is there any other way to access key-value pairs from the $resource.get other than using $promise.then?

Edit: Here is my original code:

Contact.service.js

```
  'use strict';

angular.module('contacts').factory('Contact', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    console.log('Iam cliked');
    return $resource('/api/contacts/:id', {id: '@_id'}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

EditController.js

```
  'use strict';

angular.module('contacts').controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$stateParams' ,'$location', '$rootScope', 'Contact',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $rootScope, Contact) {
        $rootScope.PAGE = 'edit';
        $scope.contact = {};
        $scope.singleContact = Contact.get({ id: $stateParams.id});

        console.log($scope.singleContact);


        $scope.singleContact.$promise.then(function(data){
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                if(key !== 'additions')
                    $scope.contact[key] = value;
                else {
                    angular.forEach(data.additions, function(value, key) {
                        $scope.contact[key] = value;
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log($scope.contact);
        });

        /*parsing my received nested json doument to have all straight key-value pairs and binding this $scope.contact to form-field directive 'record=contact'

I am successful doing this and able to display in web page but when I try to $update any of the field in the webpage it doesnt update. Because it is not being Resource object but it is just the object
please see the images attached[![enter image description here][1]][1]*/




        $scope.delete = function(){
            $scope.contact.$delete();
            $location.url('/contacts');
        };
    }
]);
```

Edit.html

```
<section data-ng-controller='EditController'>
<h2>{{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}</h2>

<form name='editContact' class='form-horizontal'>
    <form-field record='contact' recordType='contactType' field='firstName' required='true'></form-field>
    <form-field record='contact' recordType='contactType' field='lastName' required='true'></form-field>
    <form-field record='contact' recordType='contactType' field='{{k}}' ng-repeat=' (k, v) in contact | contactDisplayFilter: "firstName" | contactDisplayFilter: "lastName" | contactDisplayFilter: "__v" | contactDisplayFilter: "_id" | contactDisplayFilter: "userName"'></form-field>

    <new-field record='contact'></new-field>

    <div class='row form-group'>
        <div class='col-sm-offset-2'>
            <button class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='delete()'>Delete Contact</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

form-field.html

```
<div class='row form-group' ng-form='{{field}}' ng-class="{'has-error': {{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid}">
<label  class='col-sm-2 control-label'>{{field | labelCase}} <span ng-if='required'>*</span></label>

<div class='col-sm-6' ng-switch='required'>
    <input ng-switch-when='true' ng-model='record[field]' type='{{recordType[field]}}' class='form-control' required ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' />

    <div class='input-group' ng-switch-default>
        <input ng-model='record[field]' type='{{recordType[field]}}' class='form-control' ng-change='update()' ng-blur='blurUpdate()' />
        <span class='input-group-btn'>
            <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='remove(field)'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-4 has-error' ng-show='{{field}}.$dirty && {{field}}.$invalid' ng-messages='{{field}}.$error'>
    <p class='control-label' ng-message='required'>{{field | labelCase}} is required.</p>
    <p class='control-label' ng-repeat='(k, v) in types' ng-message='{{k}}'>{{field | labelCase}} {{v[1]}}</p>
</div>
```

function in form-field.js directive

```
                $scope.blurUpdate = function(){
                if($scope.live!== 'false'){
                    console.log($scope.record);
                    $scope.record.$update(function(updatedRecord){
                        $scope.record = updatedRecord;
                    });
                }
            };
```

So in the above $update gives error. saying not a function.

I want the same format in $scope.singleContact and $scope.contact. How can I achieve this?

[image: see the difference between the object shown?]

Comment: Is parse the right word? You're saying `$scope.var` is a string instead of a javascript object?

Comment: Ok let me keep it clear.. if $scope.var receives nested json.. How would I be able to access the received json documents key-value pairs without using $promise.then?

Comment: I think i'm understanding better. Could you post the 2 code examples?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand but you want something like this:

```
Contact.get({id: $stateParams.id}, function (contact){
    $scope.var = contact;
});
```

right?

It will return te promise and you will be able to use the data before loading the templates

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple things:

**Promises will not return values synchronously**

You have to use a `then` function call. The line

```
$scope.singleContact = Contact.get({ id: $stateParams.id});
```

will not put your data into the `$scope.singleContact` variable immediately because that line returns a Promise and goes onto the next line without waiting for the web request to return. That's how Promises work. If you aren't familiar with them, it might not be a bad idea to read up on them. A consequence of this is that **everything** inside your controller (or wherever this code is) that needs a working value in `$scope.singleContact` needs to be inside of a `then` block or in some way guaranteed to be run *after* the promise is resolved.

So I think you want (as @EDDIE VALVERDE said):

```
Contact.get({ id: $stateParams.id}, function(data) {
    $scope.singleContact = data;
    $scope.contact = data;
});
```

I'm not sure what the rest of the code is doing but it looks to me like it is trying to do a deep copy of `$scope.singleContact`. My guess is that you're just doing this cause the promise stuff wasn't working and you can remove it...
Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Contact.get(...).then is not a function. I think it could not be written that way. 
If you see I wanted to parse (not read) the nested JSON document before html page prints are the Keys in the JSON document as Labels and Values in input fields..

Comment: Hey, I do not have a problem in reading the $resource.get() and then putting it into some $scope var and then parsing it.. But when I do parse the nested JSON received document, it is not being as a Resource obj but being just normal object.. So I am getting problem while $update. Let me post my whole code. Hope it helps..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding.  "it is not being as a Resource obj but being just a normal object.. So I am getting problem while $update."  I don't  understand.

Comment: attached the image. Please check.. The console image when says Resource(...) it updates fine.. but When it says Object(...) then update doesn't happen..

This difference is because, I am parsing $scope.singleContact to $scope.contact using $promise.then

Comment: parse is not the right word. parse implies you are reading through a string, like parsing a *.js file or *.java file.

Comment: please check the attached image and please let me know why is that difference. and what could be done..

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I think I understand.  Okay, for 1 I would not add $resource objects to your scope.  IMO the scope is intended to be a **Model** in the **MVC** paradigm.  A $resource is kindof like a model, but it's performing network calls and it's got a bunch of stuff other than data.  If you put $resource in your model you remove any clear layer where you can manipulate and transform the data as it comes back from the server. And I'm sure there are other reasons. So I would not add $resource objects like Contact directly to the scope.  That being said, I think you want to add a new update function, like you did with delete, only something like this:

```
    $scope.update= function(args){

        //make network call and update contact
        Contact.$update({/*data from args?*/});

        //get the data i just saved
        Contact.$get({/* id from args */}, function(result) {
            $scope.contact = result;
        });

        //other stuff?
    };
```

That's my first thought, anyway...